# Send auth context to firebase callable function in unittest

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have been working on a firebase project in which I created a cloud function that creates documents in firestore. This is the function -

```js
export const createExpenseCategory = functions
  .region("europe-west1")
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => { // data is a string
    if (!context.auth?.uid) { // check that requesting user is authenticated
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "unauthenticated",
        "Not Authenticated"
      );
    }

    const res = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("/categories/")
      .where("uid", "==", context.auth.uid)
      .get();

    const categoryExists = res.docs.find((doc) => doc.data().name === data); // check that there are not duplicates.
  //  doc looks like this -
  //  {
  //    "name": "Food",
  //    "uid": "some_long_uid"
  //  }

    if (categoryExists) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "already-exists",
        `Category ${data} already exists`
      );
    }

    return admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("/categories/")
      .add({ name: data, uid: context.auth.uid });
  });
```

As you can see, at the beginning of the function I check whether the user that sent the request is authenticated with the `context` parameter. Everything works fine when I play around with it in my web app, but I have been trying to figure out a way to create a unittest for this function. My problem is that I can't really figure out how to create an authenticated request to make sure that my function doesn't fail every time. I tried to look online for any documentation but couldn't seem to find any.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unit test your functions using the [`firebase-functions-test`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing) SDK. The guide mentions you can mock the data within the [`eventContext`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions.eventcontext#eventid) or `context` parameter passed to your function. This works for mocking the `uid` field of the `auth` object:

```js
// Left out authType as it's only for RTDB
wrapped(data, {
  auth: {
    uid: 'jckS2Q0'
  }
});
```

The guide uses [`mocha`](https://mochajs.org/#getting-started) for testing, but you can use other testing frameworks. I made a simple test to see if it would work and I could send the mock `uid` to the function, which worked as expected:

**index.js**

```js
exports.authTest = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {
    if(!context.auth.uid){
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unauthenticated', 'Missing Authentication');
    }

    const q = await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('uid', '==', context.auth.uid).get();
    const userDoc = q.docs.find(doc => doc.data().uid == context.auth.uid);

    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userDoc.id).update({name: data.name});
});
```

**index.test.js**

```js
const test = require('firebase-functions-test')({
    projectId: PROJECT_ID
}, SERVICE_ACCTKEY); //Path to service account file
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

describe('Cloud Functions Test', () => {
    let myFunction;
    before(() => {
        myFunction = require('../index.js');
    });

    describe('AuthTest', () => {
        it('Should update user name in UID document', () => {
            const wrapped = test.wrap(myFunction.authTest);

            const data = {
                name: 'FooBar'
            }
            const context = {
                auth: {
                    uid: "jckS2Q0" //Mocked uid value
                }
            }

            return wrapped(data, context).then(async () => {
                //Asserts that the document is updated with expected value, fetches it after update
                const q = await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('uid', '==', context.auth.uid).get();
                const userDoc = q.docs.find(doc => doc.data().uid == context.auth.uid);
                assert.equal(userDoc.data().name, 'FooBar');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Let me know if this was useful.

Comment: @CoolSteve did you need more help in creating your unit test?